# Drupal webform edit exsitng response

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I have a webform, where the user fills in fields like - Name,Age,Gender etc.....

The users come in and fill this data, however I want to give them a functionality where they can edit their previous responses via the same webform (Like a pre filled webfrom, with their previous responses).

I am investigating about storing every response as draft (are there any drawbacks with that?), but then I would loose on the end form (submit form), actions :(

Also is there a way to store responses as draft even after submit (so the users can find their previous responses, pre filled in the same webform.)

Comment: I think webform provide edit link for edit their submission detail.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what submit actions you are looking to use, this might not work.

Try creating a custom content type with the fields you need, and then allow users to create / edit that content type. You can then use Drupal's built in editing and publishing to do what you are asking.

Rules and/or Triggers can normally handle the typical submit actions like send an email.

Comment: I dont want my users to create anything......

Sorry, May be I wasn't clear enough... what I wan to do is..

When the user fills in the webform built using - (Webform modules) and submits it... 

he should be able to edit/change the values give before, in the same wizard, it should act like a profile editing wizard...